# Laravel 4 - Eloquent way to attach a where clause to a relationship when building a collection

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This may be a dupe but I've been trawling for some time looking for a proper answer to this and haven't found one yet.

So essentially all I want to do is join two tables and attach a where condition to the entire collection based on a field from the joined table.

So lets say I have two tables:

```
users:
   -id
   -name
   -email
   -password
   -etc

user_addresses:
   -address_line1
   -address_line2
   -town
   -city
   -etc
```

For the sake of argument (realising this may not be the best example) - lets assume a user can have multiple address entries. Now, laravel/eloquent gives us a nice way of wrapping up conditions on a collection in the form of scopes, so we'll use one of them to define the filter.

So, if I want to get all the users with an address in smallville, I may create a scope and relationships as follows:

*Users.php (model)*

```
class users extends Eloquent{
    public function addresses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Address');
    }

    public function scopeSmallvilleResidents($query){
        return $query->join('user_addresses', function($join) {
                    $join->on('user.id', '=', 'user_addresses.user_id');
                })->where('user_addresses.town', '=', 'Smallville');
    }
}
```

This works but its a bit ugly and it messes up my eloquent objects, since I no longer have a nice dynamic attribute containing users addresses, everything is just crammed into the user object.

I have tried various other things to get this to work, for example using a closure on the relationship looked promising:

//this just filters at the point of attaching the relationship so will display all users but only pull in the address where it matches

```
User::with(array('Addresses' => function($query){
                $query->where('town', '=', 'Smallville');
            }));
```

//This doesnt work at all

```
User::with('Addresses')->where('user_addresses.town', '=', 'Smallville');
```

So is there an 'Eloquent' way of applying where clauses to relationships in a way that filters the main collection and keeps my eloquent objects in tact? Or have I like so many others been spoiled by the elegant syntax of Eloquent to the point where I'm asking too much?

Note: I am aware that you can usually get round this by defining relationships in the other direction (e.g. accessing the address table first) but this is not always ideal and not what i am asking.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Apparently it works as you said, and this might be off-topic, but shouldn't you be using `hasMany()` rather than `belongsToMany()` when setting up your `addresses()` relationship?

Comment: Yes it should - a point for you sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, there is no means by which you can filter primary model based on a constraint in the related models.
That means, you can't get only `Users` who have `user_address.town = 'Smallwille'` in one swipe.

Personally I hope that this will get implemented soon because I can see a lot of people asking for it (including myself here).

The current workaround is messy, but it works:

```
$products = array();
$categories  = Category::where('type', 'fruit')->get();
foreach($categories as $category)
{
 $products = array_merge($products, $category->products);
}
return $products;
```

Comment: Will array_merge work if products is an object? Wouldnt I have to run the result through toArray() first? Do you know of a feature request for a more elegant solution that I can keep an eye on?

Comment: I think it will work but anyway calling toArray() would definitely speed it up so it should be a good thing to do. I remember Taylor discussing something like this on github for the `has()` method because it currently supports only filtering by the count of the objects. His response was that he will work on that and closed the issue. So my guess is that in future we could write something like  `$products = Product::has('Category', function($query){ $query->where('type', 'fruit'); })->get();`

Comment: Thanks for your help - not the answer I wanted but at least I can stop trawling Google. I guess we'll have to wait for Taylor... I dont think anyone has much chance of doing this with a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the question there is a way to filter the adresses first and then use eager loading to load the related users object. As so:

`$addressFilter = Addresses::with('Users')->where('town', $keyword)->first();
$users= $addressFilter->users;`

of course bind with belongsTo in the model.

///*** And in case anyone reading wants to also use pre-filtered Users data you can pass a closure to the 'with'

```
$usersFilter = Addresses::with(array('Users' => function($query) use ($keyword){ 
        $query->where('somefield', $keyword);
    }))->where('town', $keyword)->first();
$myUsers = $usersFilter->users;
```